# Nginx Ingress Adding Security Group Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx-ingress

I am running an Amazon EKS cluster with the control plane in subnets across 5 availability zones.  When I install the Bitnami nginx ingress controller [Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller), a load balancer is created as expected.  I've noticed a series of inbound rules also get added to the security group attached to my managed node group.

The first set are TCP rules over two different ephemeral ports.  There is one rule for each subnet CIDR with a description of `kubernetes.io/rule/nlb/health={load-balancer-name}`.  In addition there is a rule for ephemeral port with a source of `0.0.0.0/0` and a description of `kubernetes.io/rule/nlb/client={load-balancer-name}`.

Finally there is a strange rule with the following settings:

| type | protocol | port range | source | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Custom ICMP - IPv4 | Destination Unreachable | fragmentation required | 0.0.0.0/0 | kubernetes.io/rule/nlb/mtu |

I have not been able to find any documentation around these SG rules or what they are used for.  In addition, they do not get destroyed when I uninstall the Helm chart.

I'm looking for documentation on what the rules are for and guidance on how to manage them using either the Helm chart or Terraform.

Comment: The point is that you don't manage them. The aws-load-balancer-controller does. Rules should get removed when the service goes away, though.

Comment: The fact that they aren't being removed is why I asked about management.  I agree though that ideally the service should be doing it on its own.

Comment: Actually reading this again, after deleting the helm chart the load balancer itself should have been deleted. Do you see errors in your aws-load-balancer-controller logs?

Comment: The load balancer does get deleted.  The issue is that the rules on the security group that were added are not deleted.  These are ingress rules on the EKS node security group.  I discovered they weren't getting deleted because I was doing some nginx testing and eventually hit the max rule count on the SG